# Do we need to standardize implicit data before putting in ALS model? If so, how?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-ml, als

I am working on creating an ALS model in Pyspark using implicit data ( retail transactional data - taking # of units bought as implicit data).

Before throwing the data into the model, do we need to do some kind of standardization/normalization of the data?
If not, how does it takes care of cases where an item is overbought or a user is an overbuyer. eg. milk is usually bought more than TVs, User1 usually buys lesser than User2?

Any pointers would be helpful. Thanks